# Microsoft Healthbot API Get scenario stack information

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

H, I'm working on a healthcare project which is using Microsoft Healthcare Bot as a tool. I followed the GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/HealthBotContainerSample/, and set it up successfully. right now what I can subscribe from the bot is activity property, using the below sample code:

```
botConnection.postActivity({type: "activity", value: jsonWebToken, from: user, name: "InitAuthenticatedConversation"}).subscribe(function (id) {

});
botConnection.activity$.filter(function(activity)
{
    return activity.type === "activity"
})
    .subscribe(function (activity) 
    {
        console.log(activity);
    });
```

and the first screenshot is what i get:

[image]
However, there is one thing I can't find any corresponding API, if I interact with bot on Azure, there is an Object with contains scenario stack, intent, score and so on (see the screenshot). But I can't find which API can help me retrieve this object,So, how to retrieve the object showing in the watch window?
[image: watch window]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it does not look like there is a way in which a trace can be logged outside of the Scenario Designer for the HealthBot. I tested this and it looks like the trace is not emitted by the bot as any sort of event or message activity and only outputs from the bot, itself.

There are a couple avenues you can take, however.

One, if you sign up for Application Insights in Azure and include the Instrumentation Key, then you can log how the application (i.e. bot) is performing. This *will* capture any trace events emitted by the bot, however, the telemetry is not the same. It will allow you to see when they are occurring. The below screenshot from Azure shows an example.

To add in Application Insights, in your HealthBot in Azure, navigate to Integration => Secrets. You can then add the Instrumentation Key and save. It generally takes a few moments for activity to populate when viewing Application Insights, so be patient.

The second thing you can do is submit a Feature Request on their GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/HealthBotContainerSample/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc) requesting trace events be made available externally for logging and inspection.

Additionally, there is a Microsoft [TechCommunity](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Healthcare-Bot/ct-p/HealthCareBot) that you can participate in. I don't know if it is monitored for issues/requests, but it is worth trying.

Hope of help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for the answer, the object you print out is not my question. If you compare the object from the watch window, which is my question, and the object you print out, you will find that they are two different things. Please see the update. Even I made it activity, I still can retrieve the object you printed out, are you able to retrieve the object from watch window using v4?

Comment: I should have been clearer in that this is purely demonstrating how to get the ‘message’ activity vs. the ‘event’ activity. This is not connecting to the HealthBot as I do not have a registration with that product, so the data in both objects will be different. However, that doesn’t matter. As it is built using BotFramework’s BotBuilder (v3 or v4) and Web Chat (can be v3 or v4), you will still be dealing with the same overall activity architecture, in which the object in question is likely a ‘message’. Have you tried matching on the ‘message’ type, yet?

Comment: I should add that, with respect to both activity objects being different, that that is ok. There are subtle differences between a ConfirmPrompt and a Suggested Action activity when comparing the two. This is true despite the ConfirmPrompt being built using Suggested Actions in its construction.

Comment: Hi Steven, I tried to swap activity to message but the result is the same as before, the only difference is the value of the key "type" changed correspondingly, but what I'm looking for seems still missing. It looks like the Object from the watch window is out of generic bot framework and could explicitly belong to healthcare bot, and no matter the context is whether a ConfirmPrompt or a Suggested Action, the value inside Object from watch window don't get influenced and only affected by user's answer.

Comment: Which scenario template did you choose and which object/item/activity are you 'watching'?

Comment: The screenshot which has a watch window, and there is an object at the top level, it has user, scenarioStack, and conversation properties, that is my target. The healthcare bot match me a scenario template during the runtime based on my input, and behind the scenes, there are LUIS, regular expression and some other things, but the mechanism is user intent recognization for all cases. a good example is the scenarioStack property of that Object, as the user-bot interaction goes further and further, there will be more and more scenarios there.

Comment: @JeremyParker, I updated my answer to reflect new findings.